# Efficiently create generator to output lists of numbers in order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to create a generator that outputs a list of incrementing numbers.
Ex.

```
[1]
[2]
..
[9]
[1,0]
[1,1]
[1,2]
..
[9,9]
[1,0,0]
[1,0,1]
```

I can do this in a brute force sort of way (not exactly right, but does not matter in this application, has leading 0s):

```
def generateNumbersStupid():
        for x1 in range(10):
                for x2 in range(10):
                        for x3 in range(10):
                                for x4 in range(10):
                                        for x5 in range(10):
                                                for x6 in range(10):
                                                        for x7 in range(10):
                                                                for x8 in range(10):
                                                                        yield [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6, x7, x8]
```

Profile

```
   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   56.083   56.083 part2_extended.py:1(<module>)
100000000   14.221    0.000   14.221    0.000 part2_extended.py:1(isGrowing)
     1278    0.001    0.000    0.004    0.000 part2_extended.py:17(meetsAdjacentCriteria)
100000000   13.181    0.000   27.452    0.000 part2_extended.py:25(isValid)
     1278    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 part2_extended.py:28(findAdjacents)
100000001    9.726    0.000   10.689    0.000 part2_extended.py:81(generateNumbersStupid)
    24310    0.031    0.000    0.046    0.000 part2_extended.py:9(inRange)
        1   17.942   17.942   56.083   56.083 part2_extended.py:92(calculateCount)
        1    0.000    0.000   56.083   56.083 part2_extended.py:99(main)
     6630    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
     9524    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
   194480    0.016    0.000    0.016    0.000 {pow}
```

But I would like to avoid the uglyiness and have something like this:

```
def generateNumbersArray(startNumber, endNumber):
        for num in range(startNumber, endNumber+1):
                number = []
                while True:
                        number.append(num%10)
                        num //=10
                        if num == 0:
                                break
                number.reverse()
                yield number
```

But this runs significantly slower.

Have also tried a cleaner:

```
def generateNumbersArray(startNumber, endNumber):
        for num in range(startNumber, endNumber+1):
                yield [int(x) for x in str(num)]
```

It is also significantly slower.

If I try to keep everything in place and not generating new arrays, it speeds it up quite a bit, but is still significantly slower.

```
def generateNumbersArrayInPlace(startNumber, endNumber):
        start = [int(x) for x in str(startNumber-1)]
        for num in range(startNumber, endNumber):
                lastIndex = len(start) - 1
                start[lastIndex] = start[lastIndex] + 1
                for digit in range(lastIndex, -1, -1):
                        if start[digit] > 9:
                                start[digit] = 0
                                if digit == 0:
                                        start.insert(0,1)
                                else:
                                        start[digit-1] = start[digit-1] + 1
                        else:
                                break
                yield start[:]
```

Profile

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   49.618   49.618 part2_extended.py:1(<module>)
 46191900    6.844    0.000    6.844    0.000 part2_extended.py:1(isGrowing)
     1278    0.001    0.000    0.004    0.000 part2_extended.py:17(meetsAdjacentCriteria)
 46191900    6.827    0.000   13.677    0.000 part2_extended.py:25(isValid)
     1278    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 part2_extended.py:28(findAdjacents)
 46191901   18.352    0.000   26.127    0.000 part2_extended.py:43(generateNumbersArray2)
     1278    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 part2_extended.py:9(inRange)
        1    9.814    9.814   49.618   49.618 part2_extended.py:92(calculateCount)
        1    0.000    0.000   49.618   49.618 part2_extended.py:99(main)
 46198530    1.865    0.000    1.865    0.000 {len}
     9524    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    10224    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {pow}
```

My question is if there is a pythonic way to do this efficiently?

Update:

@ggorlen  something like

```
def generateNumbersItertools(startRange, endRange):
        gen = product([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], repeat=8)
        while True:
                cur = next(gen)
                yield [x for x in cur]
```

Profile:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   90.430   90.430 part2_extended.py:1(<module>)
100000000   14.977    0.000   14.977    0.000 part2_extended.py:1(isGrowing)
        1    0.000    0.000   90.430   90.430 part2_extended.py:101(main)
     1278    0.001    0.000    0.004    0.000 part2_extended.py:17(meetsAdjacentCriteria)
100000000   14.289    0.000   29.317    0.000 part2_extended.py:25(isValid)
     1278    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 part2_extended.py:28(findAdjacents)
100000001   34.681    0.000   40.798    0.000 part2_extended.py:62(generateNumbersItertools)
    24310    0.032    0.000    0.048    0.000 part2_extended.py:9(inRange)
        1   20.315   20.315   90.430   90.430 part2_extended.py:94(calculateCount)
     6630    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
     9524    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
100000001    6.116    0.000    6.116    0.000 {next}
   194480    0.016    0.000    0.016    0.000 {pow}
```

Is also very slow.

Comment: Not sure if there is a faster method than the last one, but why do you need this in the first place? Generators are not free and you can have better performance if you replace the code where you consume this generator with a simple `for` loop.

Comment: The easiest way to create such thing is to `from itertools import combinations_with_replacement`

Comment: @politinsa `combinations_with_replacement` generates fixed length subsequences.

Comment: @Selcuk It became mostly an academic question to learn what was going on once I saw how slow the second version was.  But moving the loops out of the generator makes it a bit faster.

Comment: @ggorlen  something like ```def generateNumbersItertools(startRange, endRange):
        gen = product([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], repeat=8)
        while True:
                cur = next(gen)
                yield [x for x in cur]```  
 
Is also very slow.

Comment: It returns tuples instead of lists (with yield and not return).

Comment: Added profiling results, you can see the generate function takes 3x longer and ends up taking the majority of the time with the itertools version.

Comment: Thanks--just curious, if you skip the nested iterator and the list comp stuff, how fast is `product` raw on your machine? Yes, it returns tuples but just for context... You don't have to edit the post, just give me the cumulative time if you don't mind.

Comment: Yes it looks to be quicker, relaxing that restriction on mutability, but then building the list removes any benefit later on.

Comment: Good to hear. How about casting to list in the caller if/when you need mutability? That must be a lot faster than the `while: True`, nested iterator and list comp hijinks. Try `for x in product(range(10, repeat=8)): list(x)`. I'd bet this is pretty reasonable.

Comment: I spoke too soon, the method of using a list comprehension is slower than using list() So that works.  That looks like the winner.

Comment: Glad it worked out, but it's still unclear whether you need `startIndex` or `endIndex`.... The we've fixed the `Stupid` code, but it seems pretty much unrelated to all the other functions you've shown. I'd also recommend cleaning up your post a bit while you're at clarifying that. I never really recommended anything like the bottom block since it just slows `product` to a crawl with a lot of extra work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without running profiles, just using `timeit` I saw massive improvement by using `itertools.product` and by combining that with `itertools.dropwhile` you no longer have the preceding zeros in the leading lists although the first output will be an empty list this is the closest to what seems your desired output:

```
generateNumbers = (list(dropwhile((0).__eq__, p)) for p in product(range(10), repeat=8))
```

This results in:

```
[]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[6]
[7]
[8]
[9]
[1, 0]
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[1, 5]
[1, 6]
[1, 7]
...
```

Comment: You're referencing the `__eq__` attribute of `(0)`.

Comment: That works. It's an object, and passing the first class function directly into the callback bypasses the usual lambda.

Comment: Correct thus more efficient than a lambda all day.

Comment: @Jab Does that code actually work for you? I'm getting hit with an `AttributeError: 'int' object has no arttribute '__eq__'`

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t figure out how to skip the initial empty list without it becoming much slower. I tried setting the comprehension to a variable and using next then yielding as well as an islice but it made it a great deal slower to my surprise.

Comment: @Kieran Moynihan what version of python are you using? I’m on 3.6 and works fine for me. Maybe a version issue?

Comment: Guess you need a lambda after all, check if the list has 1 element and if so, don't drop it. It shouldn't be that major of a hit I would think, just one extra function call and conditional per iteration. This code works fine on python 3.8. Anyway, it might not help much until we get some clarification about `startIndex`/`endIndex` mess.

Comment: @Jab My mistake, just checked it on my 3.8 install and it works fine. Not sure what version it started working on, but somewhere between 2.7 and 3.6 I suppose.

Comment: Or just skip the first element but I tried the 2 obvious ways and maybe it’s because I did the test on my phone using Pythonista maybe not.

Comment: If you skip the first element, you need to prepend a 0 to preserve the logic. If the caller doesn't mind doing that....

Comment: Dropping the 0's on this one is quite a bit slower than using product alone on my machine.

Comment: Although it is what OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I ran some tests of my own comparing your "stupid" function `generateNumbersStupid()` to functions using `itertools.product()`, and just as the comments have been saying, it is faster.

For each of the following functions I ran 10 trials and took the average time (bear in mind, I iterated through all elements in the generator returned by the functions during the execution time):

**stupid function**

```
def generateNumbersStupid():
    for x1 in range(10):
            for x2 in range(10):
                    for x3 in range(10):
                            for x4 in range(10):
                                for x5 in range(10):
                                        for x6 in range(10):
                                            for x7 in range(10):
                                                for x8 in range(10):
                                                    yield [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8]
```

Average Time: `16.5137999535 sec`

**itertools.product() generator**

```
def generateNumbersItertools():
    return product(range(10), repeat=8)
```

Average Time: `3.82409999371 sec`

It cleans up the code, as per your original desire, and it executes faster. Can't see the need for using a `generator` in this case, especially given how much faster returning and iterating through the `list` is.

Comment: Yes, it is faster, but then other code breaks because it is expecting a list, because that is returning a tuple instead of a list.

Comment: @ggorlen My mistake, didn't check that `itertools.product()` was already returning a `generator` for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive generator that gives sequences of a specified length with your requirement:

```
def f(length):
    if length == 1:
        for i in range(1,10):
            yield [i]
    else:
        for ls in (x for x in f(length-1)):
            for i in range(10):
                yield ls + [i]
```

So, you can invoke it with arbitrary length. `[x for i in range(1,3) for x in f(i)]` will result in:

```
[[1],
 [2],
 [3],
 [4],
 [5],
 [6],
 [7],
 [8],
 [9],
 [1, 0],
 [1, 1],
 [1, 2],
 [1, 3],
 [1, 4],
 ...
```

And if you are after a generator:

```
for item in (x for i in range(1, some_number) for x in f(i)):
    #do stuff
```